# Get error status code webview swift 2

Tags: ios, webview, swift2

I want to get error status code when my WebView is loaded.
When I open the connexion I use this code :

```
let simpler = "http://www.example.com"
let url = NSURL(string: simpler)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
webview.loadRequest(request)
```

I have found this code but I obtain errors so it's not working :

[Check URL of Loaded WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006658/check-url-of-loaded-webview)

I want to get the errors in the ViewDidLoad

Comment: check out UIWebViewDelegate's didFailLoadWithError

Comment: I want to see if in the webview I obtain 404, 501 errors etc ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :-

```
        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")!

        var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        //request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);
```